# How do I go from Varchar string into Unix time type? Greenplum

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, varchar, greenplum

I'm fairly inexperienced with SQL let alone PostgreSQL so appreciate your help.

Let's say we have a varchar column called ID that is a combination of IP address and a unix epoch time string.

So when I run this query:

```
SELECT substring(b.id from char_length (r.IP_address)+2 for 10), b.id, r.ip_address
FROM bq b
INNER JOIN event r ON r.visitor_id::TEXT = b.id::TEXT 
LIMIT 3;
```

Output

```
substring   id  ip_address
1460854333  97.128.39.256.1460854333288493  97.128.39.256
```

So the output of the substring is a unix time stamp but it is in a varchar format. How do I convert the varchar into a unix timestamp? Ultimately I am going to convert that time stamp into date I just don't think I can directly go from the varchar of a unix string to a date?

Comment: `to_timestamp()` function work well with string datatypes

Comment: How would you define Unix element of it? as the string isn't in date format...

Comment: Greenplum uses a very old version of PostgreSQL, 8.3 in the most recent version. What is your output from `SELECT version();`?

Comment: Actually Kyle's edit of output type solved it. I thought I could just use to_timestamp directly and it was stating an error message of "HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types."

I'm a newb. Thank  you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Terra said, use the `to_timestamp()` function:

```
# select to_timestamp('1460854333') ;
      to_timestamp
------------------------
 2016-04-16 17:52:13-07
(1 row)
```

If a date is the type you're after, just add the `::date` cast:

```
# select to_timestamp('1460854333')::date ;
      to_timestamp
------------------------
 2016-04-16
(1 row)
```

The function is basically executing this:

```
select ('epoch'::timestamptz + '1460854333'::float * '1 second'::interval) ;
```

Comment: Weirdly my postgres doesn't have that function....any other work around where I can convert that substring?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the equivalent statement to the `to_timestamp()` function, although every version of Greenplum should have that function in `pg_catalog`. Please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi Kyle thanks!. The changing to ::float helped in the first run through

select to_timestamp(id::float)::date  that solved. Thank  you so much for pointing me in the right direction! 

I'm sure these are simple for you but it helps greatly for those just learning!